# Google API access without user interaction

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-api, service-accounts, non-interactive

I have some actions for Chrome OS that I would like to create using a background service. I am able to do one time setup but there will be no possibility for user interaction to authenticate in a browser for the calls during execution.

I've been reading through [this Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#httprest_1) and found:

```
If the API you want to call has a service definition published in the [Google APIs GitHub repository][2], you can make authorized API calls using a JWT instead of an access token.
```

However, I can't seem to figure out what they mean by 'service definition' in that repository. Can someone help me understand where I find a list of APIs/actions that are available through these methods?

I also found [this stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19766912/how-do-i-authorise-an-app-web-or-installed-without-user-intervention) which talks about using a refresh token. This was written a couple years ago - does anyone have insight into why this may be a BAD idea? I'm considering going this route but am not sure I fully understand all the implications of doing so. Essentially an admin would make a refresh token and load it into the application, where it could then be used to complete the background tasks for an indefinite amount of time (by refreshing the token in my service).

Comment: What programming language are you using and what api are you trying to access?

Comment: I'm using PowerShell and I'm trying to access the ChromeOS APIs, namely updating a device, disabling and reenabling them

Comment: If you get service account authentication working with PowerShell i would love to see the code.

Comment: I'm wanting to explore using the refresh token option mentioned in my post but I'm still doing some research around possible implications of that approach. Google documentation seems a bit vague on the actual ways that refresh tokens can end up being expired.